# Having a python arg set another flag as true in addition to itself

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

Using arg parse, I have two arguments. I want the second to automatically make the first true, even if the first is not called. Is there any way to do this?

Basic gist of what I want:

```
parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--verbose-with-bonus', action='store_true')

parser.parse_args('--verbose-with-bonus'.split())
Namespace(verbose=True, verbose_with_bonus=True)
```

Comment: Just check afterwards whether either has been set, and update the attributes accordingly. I don't think you can do it directly in `argparse`.

Comment: Would it be possible to have the parser throw an error if verbose is used without verbose_with_bonus?

Comment: Again, probably not natively, but you can throw your own! You can make them e.g. [mutually exclusive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion), too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially with `store_true` arguments, it is easy to implement your own checks after parsing, e.g.

```
 if args.verbose_with_bonus:
     args.verbose = True
```

or

```
 if args.verbose_with_bonus and not args.verbose:
     parser.error('naughty user')
```

The documentation talks about a 'count' argument type:

```
'count' - This counts the number of times a keyword argument occurs. For example, this is useful for increasing verbosity levels:

>>>
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--verbose', '-v', action='count')
>>> parser.parse_args('-vvv'.split())
Namespace(verbose=3)
```

So you could treat `verbose=1` as your plain verbose, and `verbose=2` as verbose_with_bonus.

It is also possible to create custom Action classes, for example, one that would set both `verbose_with_bonus` and `verbose`.  But I suspect that's overkill in your case.  (ps. there are lots of SO answers about writing a custom Action class).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I agree that if I want to do anything more complex I should go the Action class route.

Answer (score 0):

```
args = parse_args()
args.verbose = args.verbose or args.verbose_with_bonus
```

might be good enough